# How to get an early warning to someone logging into a server

Tags: linux, security

I like to be notified when someone is logged into one of my Linux servers, and also be able to find out what the  location of the login attempt. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, thanks for answering the question. However, I have done it slightly differently, I have an one-line command in the global bashrc file.

Here's my solution

```
echo "Login on" `hostname` `date` | mail -s "Login on `hostname` `who am i | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/[()]//g' | cut -f1 -d "." | sed 's/-/./g'`" admin@example.com
```

Assuming that you have the mailutils package installed on your Linux machine.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux login process is primarily ruled by [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_SAG.html) (Pluggable Authentication Modules for Linux) which is a suite of shared libraries that enable the local system administrator to choose how applications authenticate users.

By default some PAM  messages are already logged to syslog so by monitoring that you can trigger notifications.

More specific you can use [**`pam_exec`**](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html) to have a specific notification command executed as part of a successful login event.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about ssh when you talk about "logged" you can use syslog and rsyslog .

For rsyslog check that : http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/ommail.html
With some setup you can send log by mail or with log system stack (elk stack , graylog2 , splunk , etc).

Comment: I quite like logstash/elasticsearch/kibana for syslogging.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use tcp_wrapper, in `/etc/hosts.allow` you can use something like this.

```
sshd : ALL : spawn (echo -e "Connected from IP %h with user %u" | mail -s "SSH Connection" info@example.com) : ALLOW
```

For more information.

```
man 5 hosts_access
```

But with this method you need to be careful if your servers are exposed to internet, because every time someone will try to connect to ssh port, you will recive an email, so i don't have this problem because i used this in a private LAN,

Second methond, in `/etc/ssh/sshrc` use something as follow.

```
echo $USER $SSH_CLIENT $(date "+%F %H-%M-%S") | mail -s "ssh connection" info@example.com
```

using the last method you will recive one mail, only when one the user is logged in your server.

Answer (score 0):

**CentOS**

Open the file ~/.bash_profile in a text editor. Append the following lines

```
IP="$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1)"
HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
NOW=$(date +"%e %b %Y, %a %r")

echo 'Someone from '$IP' logged into '$HOSTNAME' on '$NOW'.' | mail -s 'SSH Login Notification' YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

If you are using **Ubuntu/Debian** 
add the same content to ~/.bashrc

There are 3 ssh client environment variables.

> SSH_CLIENT='192.168.223.17 36673 22'
>
> SSH_CONNECTION='192.168.223.17 36673 192.168.223.229 22'
>
> SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/6

**SSH_CLIENT** shows the address of the client system, the outgoing port number on the client system and the incoming port on the server. **SSH_CONNECTION** shows the address of the client, the outgoing port on the client, the address of the server and the incoming port on the server. **SSH_TTY** names the pseudo-terminal device, abbreviated Ppty, on the server used by the connection